# Snort detection_filter not alerting

Tags: snort

I am trying to implement a simple flooding attack alert by using this rule:

`alert tcp any any <> any any (msg:"Flooding attack!";detection_filter:track by_dst, count 4, seconds 1; sid:1000036)`

Even if I have traffic 10 Pkts/sec (calculated by Snort) all going to the same destination and it does not alarm.

`/var/snort/log/alert` is empty.

Packet traces on the snort box shows that all packets are being seen.

Snort version 2.9.9.0

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I use this working alert rule for SYN Floods.

`alert tcp any any -> 192.168.1.3 any (msg:"TCP SYN Flooding attack detected"; flags:S; threshold: type threshold, track by_dst, count 10 , seconds 30; sid: 5000001; rev:1;)`

Where:

- The "threshold" keyword means that this rule logs every event on this SID during a 30 second interval. So, if less than 10 events occur in 30 seconds, nothing gets logged. Once an event is logged, a new time period starts.
- The "track" by_dst keyword means track by destination IP.
- The "count" keyword means count number of events.
- The "seconds" keyword means time period over which count is accrued.
- The "sid" keyword is used to uniquely identify Snort rules. This information allows output plugins to identify rules easily. This option should be used with the "rev" keyword.

  - sid < 100 Reserved for future use
  - 100 < sid < 999,999 Rules included with the Snort distribution
  - sid > 1,000,000 Used for local rules

There are further information [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101171&seqNum=6) and [here](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node31.html).